# Sum of the first $n$ terms of polynome

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

There are several related questions here, but none seem to have helped me so far. There is an exercise in my book that goes like this:

Determine the sum of the first $n$ elements of $$x^3 + x^5 + x^7 + ...$$
However the theoretic/general approach in my book is very confusing.

So far I've got $$x_k = x^{2k+1}$$

Could someone explain to mo how I can find the sum of this expression? I know the sum of a geometric series is $$ s_k = a\frac{1 - x^{k+1}}{1-x}$$ but this does not help my very much.

I think if I understand this example, this general approach becomes much more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is
$$x^3+x^5+x^7+\cdots+x^{2n+1}.$$
Let it be $S$. Then, consider
$$x^2S=\color{red}{x^5+x^7+\cdots+x^{2n+1}}+x^{2n+3}$$
$$S=x^3+\color{red}{x^5+x^7+\cdots+x^{2n+1}}$$
Subtracting the latter from the former gives you
$$(x^2-1)S=x^{2n+3}-x^3.$$
Hence, if $x^2-1\not= 0$, i.e. $x\not=\pm 1$, then we get$$S=\frac{x^{2n+3}-x^3}{x^2-1}.$$
The cases $x=\pm 1$ are trivial.

Comment: Awesome! This was really what I was looking for. The last thing I'm curious about is how do u find the $x^2$ to multiply $S$ with ? In this case it's not really difficult to see, but I can imagine this can get complicated. Or do u just see what operation u have to do to go from $x^3$ to $x^5$ (i.e. the first two terms) ?

Comment: @RobinHaveneers: Not only the first two terms. The $x^2$ comes from that we have $x^5=x^2\times x^3,x^7=x^2\times x^5,x^9=x^2\times x^7$ and so on.

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes a lot of sense! Thanks a lot.